# Iterate through two list

Tags: python, ip-address

```
import ipaddress
from ipaddress import ip_network

MY_VPC_SUBNETS = ["10.0.0.0/8", "172.16.0.0/12", "192.168.0.0/16"]
MY_SG_IPS = ["172.16.1.34/32", "10.16.0.0/12", "172.16.12.0/28", "10.15.90.2/32", "60.20.15.0/24","76.0.0.0/8"]

security_group_rules=[]
allowed_ips=[]

for network in MY_VPC_SUBNETS:
    internal_network = ipaddress.ip_network(network)
    allowed_ips.append(internal_network)


for rule_ip in MY_SG_IPS:
    sg_ip = ipaddress.ip_network(rule_ip)
    security_group_rules.append(sg_ip)


security_group_rules.sort()
allowed_ips.sort()

for x in security_group_rules:
    for y in allowed_ips:
        a = ip_network(x)
        b = ip_network(y)

        if a.subnet_of(b):
            print(a)
```

So, this works and prints IPs in the MY_SG_IPS which are in subnet of ips in MY_VPC_SUBNETS, but I am having trouble listing the ips which are not part of any subnet in the list MY_VPC_SUBNETS.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use memoization to track whether an IP has been deemed valid.

Use a dictionary to track each IP and whether or not it has been deemed valid as follows...

```py
# Use dict to track who is in a subnet
visited = { ip: False for ip in allowed_ips }

for x in security_group_rules:
    for y in allowed_ips:
        a = ip_network(x)
        b = ip_network(y)

        if a.subnet_of(b):
            visited[y] = True;
            print(a)
            
# Check which IPs are not visited
ips_not_in_subnet = [x for x in visited if not visited[x]]
```

Comment: Thanks..let me check that out !

Comment: @sks did it work for you? If yes, then please mark the answer as accepted `n___n`